# JTCalendar Objective-C to Swift translation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm having issue here trying to translate the `Objective-C` codes into `Swift`

```
[self.calendar setMenuMonthsView:self.calendarMenuView]; 
[self.calendar setContentView:self.calendarContentView]; 
[self.calendar setDataSource:self];
```

I downloaded the https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar and is trying to translate the ViewController.m codes.

I've tried `self.calendar = self.calendarMenuView.setMenuMonthsView` but it doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using JTCalendar in Swift. The code is

```
self.calendar.menuMonthsView = self.calendarMenuView
self.calendar.contentView = self.calendarContentView
self.calendar.dataSource = self
```